# Azure Time Series Insights Gen2 slower than preview?

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

We have a couple of environments still running Time Series Insights Preview version. This is really fast and we are really satisfied by it. However, new environments really seem a lot slower with the official release. Warm path extraction is a lot slower, but still doable, while cold path extraction becomes unbearable.

EDIT: We need to add &storeType=WarmStore if we would like to query warm data. Cool! This works really fast again! Question about cold store still persists:

It is hard to compare the different environments, because the datasets are not exactly the same, but for our new environment we have about 4.5 TB sensor data imported in TSI.

The following screenshot shows a query that tries to retrieve one minute of data for one device (each device only sends data each 10 seconds) in the far past of 2018. However, the server returns the call after 30 seconds with a continuationtoken, saying it couldn't retrieve all the 6 values in time. Sometimes it manages to return all 6 of the values, but it still takes 30 seconds.

[image]

My internet download speed, while performing the query, was over 80 Mb per second, so that shouldn't be an issue either.

Is this something we should be worried about in the new release?

Comment: Wondering if you are aware and not overcoming any of the Query Limits as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/reference-api-limits#query-apis---limits ?

Comment: Rens--I'm glad that you're getting really fast warm store queries, but I still would request that you submit a support ticket via the portal to get some traction re your cold store perf. I see someone down voted that below ha, BUT the product group will investigate if you submit the ticket! Please provide both Azure resource IDs, and the request bodies of the queries that had different perf.

Answer (score 0):

please submit a support ticket through the Azure portal with all of these details and the product team will investigate.

Comment: Hi Ranah, Thank you for your reply, and comment. I'll remove this question soon from StackOverlflow and post it as a ticket for Microsoft to analyse. You are right, as that this is ticket more suited for Microsoft support, rather than StackOverflow. My Apologies